# What's the difference between 星期X and 周X?

Tags: meaning, difference, word, synonyms

When accepting an answer, I noticed that the example used the word 周三 for *Wednesday*,  but in my grammar, the days of the week are 星期一, 星期二, etc...

They seem both correct but, what's the difference? Is one more common, or are they simply used in difference situations?

Comment: a slightly fix: 周日 is not equal to 周天
周日 = Sunday
周天 is the opposite of weekend (週末), yes, it's weekdays

Comment: @AllenSt.Clair Never heard of the word “周天”, at least in mainland.

Comment: @CoderTian Yes, it used in HK often but not in mainland.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You have 3 methods when talking about the seven days of the week.

> 1. 星期[X]
> 2. 礼拜[X]
> 3. 周[X]

Here, "X" represents "一，二，三,四，五，六" for "Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday, Saturday". For case 1 and 2, X could be "日" or "天" for Sunday,for case 3, X should be "日" for Sunday.

**What' the difference?** 
Well, I think the 星期 and 周 are common to see, while 礼拜 is less but still common(I think it's the personal or regional perference. Thanks for fefe's suggestion). 礼拜 originates from Christianity, and in ordinary life, each type is accepatble.

**Why did I use "周三" in that example?**
Because I used "本周二" in that example, then why I used "本周二"? When you want to express "this Tuesday", you could say

> 1. 本周二
> 2. 这个星期二
> 3. 这周星期二
> 4. 本周星期二

Each of them is interchangeable. You see, "本周二" is the shortest form, so I used that. When you are talking about the days for a specific week, I think 周 is more common(please note that 周 means week).

Comment: 礼拜 is often heard in spoken language in my hometown.

Comment: @fefe  OK, I have never lived in the northern area. I just think 礼拜 is less common in the life around me. Thanks for your reminder. I will edit my answer.

Comment: Well, I think it will differ in different places.

Comment: 礼拜 is more common in my hometown too.

Comment: Just adding, 礼拜 seemed pretty common when I was living in Beijing as well.

Comment: "Libai" is common in many parts of China. The curiousest thing I've noticed is that speakers of dialects where 礼拜 is common (such as Cantonese) tend to use 星期 when using Mandarin, presumably because 星期 is taught as the 'better' form.

Comment: Note : "周天" have some other meaning (related to Chinese ancient philosophy, not easy to explain). So you should NOT say "周天" for Sunday, but "周日“ is perfectly OK.

Comment: 礼拜 used in some languaage. In fact, In Taiwanese Minnan Language. 礼拜 is as know as '拜'. like 拜一、拜二, and 礼拜 mean Sunday. It may related to Christianity.

Answer (score 2):

I don't feel there is much difference in these two expression. There maybe some personal preference though.

In formal situations, the 星期 version should be preferred.

Answer (score 2):

They are equal with slightly difference:

周X，specific to "this week"，means "someday of this week"
星期X，for general cases，means "someday of any week"

Answer (score 1):

The difference is that you may use 星期天, but not *周天; and you may use 周末, but not *星期末.

Comment: OK, what about 周日 then?

Comment: 周日 can mean either Sunday or weekday (in China iirc), depending on the region where it is used. Beginners should stick to 星期天 for more precision. 周天 means a day (any day)

Answer (score 1):

星期X is more written word.
周X is more spoken word.
But in most cases, you can switch those words equally.

Answer (score 1):

Could be regional difference. Some regions see more 星期x, some more 周x, some even 礼拜x. There could be personal preferences as well. I tend to say 星期x but 下周x and 上周x instead of 下星期x and 上星期x.

In formal situations, say 星期x; 本周x, 下周x, 上周x are also used, but not 星期天, say 星期日, 本周日, 下周日, etc instead.

Answer (score 1):

they are the same, even 星期天 (星期日, they are the same, means Sunday) are so-called 周天 (in fact it should be 周日)

周一 － 周六 ＝ 星期一 － 星期六

周日 ＝ 星期日，星期天

but we seldom use 周天

also, 礼拜x is exactly the same (礼拜天 and 礼拜日 are ok for use)

Answer (score 0):

It's a mistake that using 礼拜 (worship) as synonym of the word 星期 (week) in some dialect. But it is so widely used and accepted by people later. 礼拜 means (going to church and make) **worship** originally, so 礼拜天 or 礼拜日 means **the day of worship** (usually Sunday) of Christian every week. That means, 礼拜天 or 礼拜日 refers to a specific day, like Sunday. There isn't any day called 礼拜一/二/三/四/五/六 grammatically, all are misused words fundamentally! You may understand it, but I suggest you do not use these terms.