# What is the difference between 星期日 and 周日?

Tags: meaning, difference, word, synonyms

I know the definition of both of these words are Sunday but in what context are they used?

Comment: Similar questions had been asked and answered.  https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/21318/whats-the-difference-between-%e5%91%a8-and-%e6%98%9f%e6%9c%9f

Answer (score 4):

周日 is formal(on TV news) and oral, 星期天 is mostly oral. 星期日 is what Cantonese use orally(Hongkong, Canton), mandarin hardly.

We also use 礼拜天(mandarin)礼拜日(Cantonese) orally a lot.

Most possible combination of is above. btw There is no 周天.

Comment: 我也從沒聽過或用過周天來表示週日。

Comment: "There is no 周天" - [yes there is](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22%E5%91%A8%E5%A4%A9%E5%8E%BB%22).

Answer (score 4):

As a native speaker in mainland China, I don't agree with that 星期日 is hardly used.

1 周 星期 礼拜

周 and 星期 are both more commonly used than 礼拜. It's hard to tell which one is more formal. It's only a matter of personal habits varying from ages and regions.

2 日 天 for Sunday

周天 and 周日 both mean Sunday. 周天 is informal.